# How to delete (free) multi dimensional struct memory in cpp?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
struct grid{
    char symbol;
    int row;
    int col;
};
```

in main function:

```
grid** gr=new gr*[ROW]; //memory allocation
for(int i=0;i<ROW;i++){
    gr[i]= new grid[COL];
}
```

I want to remove specific (not all) symbol from the struct gr.
for example

```
delete[] gr[i][j];
```

i tried :

```
delete[] gr[i][j].symbol;
delete[] gr[i][j].row;
delete[] gr[i][j].col;
```

and i also tried:

```
delete[] gr[i][j];
```

none of its worked. I have read that i need to delete inside elements first then delete struct itself, but I dont want to delete struct completely. What to do to remove only some of my two dimensional struct array?

Comment: someone must have told you that you need lots of `delete` in c++. it was a lie. Better use `std::vector` (and no `delete` at all)

Comment: You do this in reverse order from what you allocated. With that said modern `c++` teaches you to its better not to use `new` and delete in a program. Instead use the standard library containers. If that does not work well there are also smart pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a jagged array.  It is an array of pointers.  Each pointer in turn points to an array of elements.

Elements cannot be deleted individually in this data structure; they are values packed together in a buffer the length of a row.

Removing a row is just `delete[] gr[i]`, then probably `gr[i]=nullptr` so you can notice it is missing.

Of course using raw new/delete is passe in modern C++; a vector of vectors, or a vector of unique ptrs to array buffers, is probably a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

### Some basics first:

To remove it all you need to do the opposite.

For every call to new you must have a call to delete.

```
    grid** gr=new gr*[ROW]; //memory allocation
    for(int i=0;i<ROW;i++){
        gr[i]= new grid[COL];
    }
```

Reverse this:

```
    for(int i=0;i<ROW;i++){
        delete [] gr[i];
    }
    delete [] gr;
```

So this gives you an idea of what you are allowed to call delete on. you can only delete what you have created via new.

### Answer to question

If you want to erase/remove an item you must manually copy all the elements after it back one space (or however you want to define the semantics of an erase).

Say I want to ease the item at `[1][5]`. This means the items at `[1][6]...[1][COL - 1]` must all be moved back one space to fill the item you have removed. There is no special command for this you must do it manually.

```
for(int loop = 6; loop < COL; ++loop) {
    gr[1][loop - 1] = gr[1][loop];
}
// Note you have not reduced the size of the array.
// So the least element still remains available.
```

But doing manual memory management is not a good idea. Is this part of an exercise for a school project; then this is fine as the next class will be in automating this.

But if you are doing this in real code then you should look at `std::vector<>`